# How do I connect passenger and driver application in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

So I am currently creating on Flutter app project right now and basically the idea is a vehicle booking system. Since I am new to flutter, I don't know how would I implement the connections between the two. Here are some of the functionalities I would like to know how would it work:

1. What do I need to do to store the Location of the passenger (but in geolocation points) to the Firestore Database I am using?
   ***For Example:** if the input of the passenger is Paris to Milan, how will it be stored in the database in terms of Latitude and Longitude?*
2. How will I fetch the above data mentioned in Number 1 in order to be displayed on the driver's screen?
3. How will the driver be notified when the passenger asks/ or book a request to the driver?

Any leads or links to how these things would work will be much appreciated. I am very much willing to learn these things, but I don't know where to start. Thanks!

**EDIT:** I am using Cloud Firestore as my database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase I strongly advise you to use Firestore and Realtime Database. You can use Realtime Database to store geolocation (latitude and longitude) when a driver is moving to pick up a passenger and the user will read those coordinates that will be used to diplay the latest saved location in a map from your choice. (*The reason behind this is to reduce your charge as Firestore charges you via action (CRUD) when realtime database charges you for storage*).
Now for Firestore you can use to store other data like Users and Drivers data ect.

For getting the location you can use many packages that can make it easy like [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) [geolocation](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocation) ...

Comment: If I used two kinds of databases (Firestore and Realtime), will it still be connected?

Comment: Is there also a package for setting the location radius of the nearby passengers, for example up to only drivers in the 500m radius will be connected to the passenger asking for booking request?

Comment: Yes it will be connected no problems as long as the logic is good, and for the second question yes there is https://pub.dev/packages/haversine_distance is one exampls

Comment: any tips how will it be connected?

Comment: Once the client accept the ride you can create a node in realtime database and save that node in Firestore that way you can retrieve coordinates from it.